# Can I include several interaction terms in a regression model?

Tags: regression, interaction

Can I test 6 two-way interactions in the same regression model (6 interaction terms and 5 simple effects in one model so 11 effects in total)? I have a theory to suspect that two separate variables will moderate the associations between three IVs and the DV. What are the benefits and drawbacks of including 6 interactions in one regression model? I also conducted a correction procedure to account for multiple tests.

Answer (score 4):

If you can actually fit the model, you *can* test almost anything you want. The power may be abysmal. The actual number of covariates in the model is not important.

Realistically, the limiting factor is the sample size versus the number of covariates you fit - or more precisely the data structure. In high dimensions, it becomes very hard to understand the distributions of your data, and which regions of the sample space are sparsely (or richly) measured. It's also harder for readers to understand what you're doing and to trust the validity of the analysis. You can't easily, for instance, just plot the covariates against the response.

That said, I often read and review and have written articles where there are over 20 or 30 or 40 covariates, including interactions. (Note: an interaction is just another covariate). There is so much information even in just the regression output, that there's no point in summarizing each effect, so the output table shows one or two key coefficient values and footnotes (models adjust for age, BMI, SES, ...), and even the methods section clarifies how each of these terms may be 4 or 5 covariates; SES for instance is a complex of education, income, employment, household structure, and marital status - which is easily 15 variables when boiled down to dummies.